# Replace data in first column of CSV

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV with many columns, and the data in the first column are dates but in the wrong format.  I am able to select just the first column and reformat the dates, but I cannot figure out how to save the new data to the existing CSV without overwriting all the other data.

```
$File = "File.csv"
$Content = Get-Content $File
$timestamp = @()
$timestamp += '"' + "timestamp" + '"'
$timestamp += $Content | Foreach { $_.Split(",") | select -first 1 } | select -skip 1 -last 10000 | where {$_ -notmatch "timestamp"} | foreach {($_).Substring(1,$_.Length-2)} | foreach {get-date ($_).ToString() -Format s} | foreach {'"' + $_ + '"'}
```

Before:

```
"timestamp"
"17-Dec-2014 07:00:00 AM"
"17-Dec-2014 07:15:00 AM"
"17-Dec-2014 07:30:00 AM"
"17-Dec-2014 07:45:00 AM"
"17-Dec-2014 08:00:00 AM"
```

After:

```
"timestamp"
"2014-12-17T07:00:00"
"2014-12-17T07:15:00"
"2014-12-17T07:30:00"
"2014-12-17T07:45:00"
"2014-12-17T08:00:00"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following data in csv format in the file `c:\temp\test.csv`

```
old_timestamp   timestamp
12/17/2014 7:00 12/17/2014 7:00
12/17/2014 7:15 12/17/2014 7:15
12/17/2014 7:30 12/17/2014 7:30
12/17/2014 7:45 12/17/2014 7:45
12/17/2014 8:00 12/17/2014 8:00
```

I would do something like this. Manipulate the old_timestamp "column" and output the changes back to the pipeline.

```
Import-CSV C:\temp\test.csv | ForEach-Object{
    $_.old_timestamp = get-date $_.old_timestamp -Format s
    $_
}
```

Sample output:

```
old_timestamp       timestamp      
-------------       ---------      
2014-12-17T07:00:00 12/17/2014 7:00
2014-12-17T07:15:00 12/17/2014 7:15
2014-12-17T07:30:00 12/17/2014 7:30
2014-12-17T07:45:00 12/17/2014 7:45
2014-12-17T08:00:00 12/17/2014 8:00
```

Now you can do what ever you want with it like output back to a file !

```
Import-CSV C:\temp\test.csv | ForEach-Object{
    $_.old_timestamp = get-date $_.old_timestamp -Format s
    $_
} | Export-Csv C:\temp\updated_test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**Simlar Approach**

You could just use a `Select-Object` statement which could do the same thing

```
Import-CSV C:\temp\test.csv | 
    Select-Object @{Name="New_TimeStamp";Expression = {get-date $_.old_timestamp -Format s}},* -ExcludeProperty old_timestamp
```

This only works as is if the column name is different. It will output the formatted column as `New_TimeStamp` as well as the rest of the data by specifying `*`. From what I have seen of your other questions this might not meld well with them but it is a solution.

Comment: This works when I don't run Export-Csv and the data is output to the screen. But when I run it with Export-Csv, the file is blank.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the `System.DateTime` class to parse your string input into a date, and convert the date back to a formatted string via its `ToString()` method.

```psh
$csv = 'C:\path\to\your.csv'

$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
$srcfmt  = 'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt'
$dstfmt  = 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'

(Import-Csv $csv) | % {
  $date = [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.timestamp, $srcfmt, $culture)
  $_.timestamp = $date.ToString($dstfmt)
  $_      # required to inject the current object back into the pipeline
} | Export-Csv $csv -NoType
```

Instead of using a loop to update the `timestamp` property you could also replace it with a [calculated property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```psh
$csv = 'C:\path\to\your.csv'

$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
$srcfmt  = 'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt'
$dstfmt  = 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'

(Import-Csv $csv) |
  select @{n='timestamp';e={
    [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.timestamp, $srcfmt, $culture).ToString($dstfmt)
  }}, other, properties, here, ...  |
  Export-Csv $csv -NoType
```

Note that either way you **must** run `Import-Csv` in a subexpression (or capture its output in a variable first), because otherwise the file would still be opened for reading when `Export-Csv` starts writing to it.

Comment: As long as the times presented in the OPs real data look like the ones in his question would there really be a need to use ParseExact? Using `Get-Date "date" -Format s` ( which is in the OP ) seems to work just fine?

Comment: @Matt `ParseExact` may not be required in this particular case, but it's the more versatile approach. `Get-Date` can handle only a subset of the formats that `ParseExact` can process.

Comment: This does work to update the CSV, but it duplicates the last row (adds another row) and I get this error:  Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: Your CSV has a trailing blank line. Fix the CSV or add a filter to exclude that line from processing: `(Import-Csv $csv) | ? { $_.timestamp } | % { ... }`