# Parse Lines from Text File based on timestamp/date, includes AM & PM

Tags: powershell, parsing, datetime, logging

I found the following post but it does not cover the inclusion of AM & PM on the lines I am attempting to parse from the text file.  I have attempted to modify what the post provided but cannot seem to get it to work.

[Delete lines based on time stamp in text file PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16286413/1630171)

Someone created our text file to include the AM & PM directly after the timestamp, but ours is a bit different in format from what is included in the post.  They appear as:

```
9/1/2016 12:00:06 AM
9/1/2016 12:15:06 AM
9/1/2016 12:30:06 AM
9/1/2016 12:45:08 AM
```

Each line is then followed by " - *status*"

I figured it would look something like this:

```
gc .\log.txt | %{if ([datetime][regex]::match($_,'^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}').Value -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)) {$_}} > .\purgedlogfile.txt
```

But I am uncertain as to how to include the AM or PM into that

Comment: _"Someone created our text file to include the AM & PM directly after the timestamp, but ours is a bit different in format"_. Can you edit your post with a sample of the 2 different files formatted?

Comment: Append `[AP]M` to your regular expression?

Comment: Manu, by "different in format", I meant to that which is referenced in the post I linked to.  In that post, their timestamp is showing as "2013-04-29 08:55:09", whereas ours is different if you see the lines of dates I posted in my original post.

Comment: Ansgar,
     I attempted that as the following but it didn't seem to work.  I received errors stating "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
gc .\log.txt | %{if ([datetime][regex]::match($_, '^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [AP]M').Value -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)) {$_}} > C:\temp\gplog\purge\purgedlogfile.txt

Comment: Then you need to actually [parse the timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27536736/1630171).

Answer (score 0):

I love regexes but I only use them when I must. This should do it:

```
gc .\log.txt | ?{if (Get-Date ('{0} {1} {2}' -f $_.Split(' ')[0..2])) -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90))} > .\purgedlogfile.txt
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work either, I am getting At C:\temp\gplog\logcleanup.ps1:1 char:67
+ ... og.txt | %{if (Get-Date '{0} {1} {2}' -f $_.Split(' ')[0..2])} -gt (G ...
+                                                                 ~
Missing statement block after if ( condition ).
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingStatementBlock

Comment: Sorry, meant to change it to a where. I'll update it.

Comment: Still didn't work unfortunately.  Here is a screenshot of the messages I am getting: [Powershell Error Message](https://photos.app.goo.gl/hzzP4gqj5tWLl1hp1)